# python subprocess: find out in the signal handler which child terminated

Tags: python, subprocess, signals

I have a python script which starts multiple commands using `subprocess.Popen`. I added a signal handler which is called if a child exits. I want to check which child terminated. I can do this by iterating over all children:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import signal

procs = []

def signal_handler(signum, frame):
    for proc in procs:
        proc.poll()
        if proc.returncode is not None:
            print "%s returned %s" % (proc.pid, proc.returncode)
            procs.remove(proc)

def main():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, signal_handler)
    procs.append(subprocess.Popen(["/bin/sleep", "2"]))
    procs.append(subprocess.Popen(["/bin/sleep","5"]))
    # wait so the main process does not terminate immediately
    procs[1].wait()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I would like to avoid querying all subprocesses. Is there a way to determine in the signal handler which child terminated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve a similar result using [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html).  You could use the [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) package instead if you didn't want to spawn the extra processes.  It has pretty much the exact same interface.  Basically, each `subprocess` call happens in a new process, which then launches your `sleep` processes.

```
import subprocess
import multiprocessing

def callback(result):
    # do something with result
    pid, returncode = result
    print pid, returncode


def call_process(cmd):
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
    p.wait()
    return p.pid, p.returncode


def main():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    pool.apply_async(call_process, [["/bin/sleep", "2"]], callback=callback)
    pool.apply_async(call_process, [["/bin/sleep", "5"]], callback=callback)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()


main()
```

Comment: This approach has two problems: 1. Without sharing data between processes, I don't have any information about the two subprocesses. 2. I have to know how many processes I want to start, because the pool only starts a certain number of workers simultaneously.

Comment: @morxa You can share data between processes with multiprocessing.  What data do you need to share?  The `Pool` is just the simplest way to kick off multiple processes.  By default it throttles the number of processes to the number of cores you have, which is usually a good idea.  But if you want more control over it, you can just use `multiprocessing.Process` and create as many as you want.